# XSLT: Copy an element where a child element matches an attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

It's abundantly clear that a variation of this question has been asked many times before. I've sifted through dozens of other questions, and still can't seem to find the answer.

Given an XML doc that looks like this:

```
<Media Attribute="4">
  <Printed SomeAttribute="3">
    <Book ID="1" OtherAttribute="2">
      <Author ID="A">Author Name1</Author>
      <Title>Some Title</Title>
    </Book>
    <Book ID="2" OtherAttribute="2">
      <Author ID="A">Author Name2</Author>
      <Title>Another Book Name</Title>
    </Book>
  </Printed>
</Media>
```

I am looking to extract the book where `@ID="1"` such that the output looks as follows:

```
<Media Attribute="4">
  <Printed SomeAttribute="3">
    <Book ID="1" OtherAttribute="2">
      <Author ID="A">Author Name1</Author>
      <Title>Some Title</Title>
    </Book>
  </Printed>
</Media>
```

I've tried different variations of the following, but it's not working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Media">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/Media/Printed/Book[@ID='1']]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can successfully copy the root node, and can successfully copy the `Book` elements recursively using `copy-of`, but I'm not sure how to match/select the parent nodes (`Media/Printed`) non-recursively while also copying the `Book` element *with* recursion at the same time.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You say "It's abundantly clear that a variation of this question has been asked many times before. I've sifted through dozens of other questions, and still can't seem to find the answer." Basically, the problem is that you're trying to learn the language "bottom up", by reading examples of code that solves specific problems and extrapolating from them. Try a bit of top-down learning to complement this: read a book that explains the concepts of the language.

Comment: Absolutely true, and a fantastic suggestion...in theory.

Comment: I'm only trying to save you time...

Comment: Understood, and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to match/select the parent nodes (`Media/Printed`) non-recursively

Why not do it recursively all the way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Printed">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Book[@ID='1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Media">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <Printed>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Printed/@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Printed/Book[@ID='1']"/>
        </Printed>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the suggestion posted by michael.hors257k was useful, it didn't produce the precise result that I wanted, mostly because I didn't properly explain what I needed. What I ended up with was:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Media">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="Printed[Book/@ID='1']">
        <Printed>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="Book[@ID='1']" />
        </Printed>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks so much!